# How to access dynamic props inside a child component's ready() in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have dynamically bind a parent's data to a child via dynamic props (`objectives` is an array which is fetched via AJAX):

```
<objective-selector :objectives="objectives"></objective-selector>
```

Inside the `objective-selector`'s `ready()` hook, I wish to do some pre-processing and somehow `this.objectives` is an observable, not an array:

```
Vue.component('objective-selector',{
   template: '#objective-selector-template',
   data:function() {
       return {
            current_selected:0
       }
   },
   ready:function(){
        // set current selected to the first non-active objective
       for (var i =0; i < this.objectives.length; ++i) {
           if (this.objectives[i].active == false) {
               this.current_selected = i;
               break;
           }
       }    
    },
   props: ['objectives']
});
```

Everything else works fine (I can use the `objectives` props as array in the template, for instance). How do I access it as an array inside ready()?

Comment: Your code looks right. If you `console.log(objectives)` inside ready what do you see, and outside this component before you pass it in is it the same?

Comment: Side note, using `++i` in your for loop will make it skip the first entry in the array, use `i++` if you want to check them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ready` function is fired sequentially before the ajax response comes back from the server.  So you need to fire the function afterward.

One easy way to do this is `$broadcast` when the value has returned from the parent.

```
compiled: function(){
    this.$on('theDataCameBackFromTheServer',function(){
        for (var i =0; i < this.objectives.length; ++i) {
               if (this.objectives[i].active == false) {
                   this.current_selected = i;
                   break;
               }
        }
    });
}
```

Another solution would be to use `watch` (this will fire every time objectives changes):

```
watch: {
     objectives: function(){
          for (var i =0; i < this.objectives.length; ++i) {
           if (this.objectives[i].active == false) {
               this.current_selected = i;
               break;
           }
       } 
     }
}
```